# Read current mouse coordinates in Windows

Tags: c++, windows

How does one read the current position of mouse in windows using C++ ?
   I want to access the the raw data from mouse and display the coordinates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the Windows API, you could GetCursorPos().  I can't compile the code right now to test it, but it should work out something like this:

```
POINT cursor;
if (GetCursorPos(&cursor)) {
    // Print out cursor.x and cursor.y
}
```

I'm sure you've done this, but be sure to include `windows.h`.